# Error with specflow in visual studio 2012 with <unitTestProvider>

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, visual-studio-2012, specflow, build-error

I am using selenium, Specflow and nUnit to run automated tests with visual studio. The code was working with visual studio 2010. After I installed visual studio 2012, selenium and Specflow again (I think I did it right), it stopped working. First, the steps didn't recognize their definitions and I think I fix it writing [Binding] in all the c# files that contains their definitions. Now when I try to build the project it shows an error that I can't solve to all feature files.

It shows 50 errors (the same number of Specflow feature files I have), they are all the same, and it says this:

`Error: Generation error: SpecFlow configuration error -> The element <unitTestProvider> may only appear once in this section`.

I don't know how to fix this. I hope somebody can help me, I am really worry because of this.

Comment: What version of SpecFlow, Selenium and NUnit are you running?

Comment: Nunit is 2.6.2, specflow 1.9.0, selenium webdriver 2.29.1

Comment: Does it still work in VS2010?

Comment: No, it doesn't work anymore in VS2010 because VS2010 is not compatible with VS2012.

Comment: Actually vs2010 sp1 can round trip with vs2012. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-compatibility-aka-project-round-tripping.aspx So what error are you seeing?

Answer (score 19):

Keep only one **attribute** as `unitTestProvider name="SpecRun"` or `unitTestProvider name="NUnit"` in **app.config**

This error is caused by **two** `'unitTestProviders'` in **app.config.**

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot more obvious when you format the App.config.

Comment: It would be good if the error message actually said what file it was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

After I install-Package SpecRun.SpecFlow -Version 1.2.0,

I've got 2 entries  unitTestProvider name="SpecRun" and unitTestProvider name="NUnit" in app.config, that coused the error.

It should be manually changed to combined one

```
 <unitTestProvider name="SpecRun+NUnit" />
```