# SpecFlow Compiling errors in VS2017

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I have just added a new specFlow feature fil, and almost 200 errors are generated when I try to build the project.

Tools:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Nunit 3.0.0
- SpecFlow 2.4.1
- SpecFlow.MSTest 2.4.1
- SpecFlow.Nunit 2.4.1
- SpecFlow.Nunit.Runner 2.4.1
- SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation 2.4.1
- SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.8.5
- SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-4-0 1.8.5

The error I'm getting:

> CS1002 ; expected , CS1003 Syntax error, '(' expected , CS8107 Feature 'readonly refernece' is not avaiable in c# 7.0. Please use language version 7.2 or greater , CS8124 Tuple must contain at least two elements etc

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: CS1002 ; expected , CS1003 Syntax error, '(' expected , CS8107 Feature 'readonly refernece' is not avaiable in c# 7.0. Please use language version 7.2 or greater , CS8124 Tuple must contain at least two elements etc

Comment: Which line in the code is that error pointing to?

Comment: Pretty much the underlying feature file: https://www.useloom.com/share/09514ef83e54424bb159d671c43e2fd3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with specflow in visual studio 2012 with <unitTestProvider>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898006/error-with-specflow-in-visual-studio-2012-with-unittestprovider)

Comment: No. I just checked it and there is only one <unitTestProvider> in the app config https://www.useloom.com/share/d4c79f9e4a3f496a9316145b7c58f052

Comment: It seems clear that you are trying to compile code that uses features beyond C# 7 with the language set to 7.0. Either change the compiler setting or change the code. :-)

Comment: If you save the feature-file, does the error in the code-behind file go away?